# How do I link the side images?

Tags: php, css, html

This is my site: http://classichits.ie/

I want to link the background image to another page.

This is the code I have so far:

```
body.boxed-layout {
   background-image:url(<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/bg4-1.jpg) !important;
   background-size:cover !important;
   background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
   background-position:center center;
}
```

The CSS is inline. How would I go about linking the background image to a different page?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your question is? Do you want the background to be clickable like an <a> tag? Or do you want to change the background to another image?

Comment: Oh. My apologies for that.
I want the side images to be clickable. Yes like the anchor tag.

Comment: If the `php echo` is inside your style.css it will not work

Comment: @CoderSte Ohk. So, how can I fix it. I am sorry, I am kinda newbie, dont know much.

Comment: @CoderSte He has the CSS inline, so that will in fact work.

Comment: @Jeroen oh I did not know he had the CSS in line, if so then that will work.

Comment: Guys, yes it's an inline CSS.

Comment: Yeah I understand that now I've just edited your post so others know it is inline CSS because at first I just thought this was in your CSS file my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your site, and are you sure you dont want to make the .wrapper clickable? boxed-layout is your whole site, so if you made that clickable the whole site would be a link.

However, if I look at your question, the answer would be to use jQuery.

```
<script>
$(".body.boxed-layout").click(function(){
window.location = "http://link/to/other/page/";
});
</script>
```

Note that this probably is not what you want!

Are you sure you don't want to make the http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/leftside.png clickable?